# Ccalling the Oracle EBS standard webservice in oracle apex using apex_web_service.make_rest_request

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apps, oracle-ebs

I am trying to call the EBS REST webservice 'assign_role' from Oracle APEX. I have deployed this webservice in EBS and got the WADL link.

Now, with this link I am able to successfully call the webservice using Postman tool by providing below JSON message :

```
{
        "InputParameters": {
            "P_REGISTRATION_DATA": [{
                    "P_REGISTRATION_DATA_ITEM": [{
                            "ATTR_NAME": "requested_for_user_id",
                            "ATTR_VALUE": 4901
                        },
                        {
                            "ATTR_NAME": "wf_role_name",
                            "ATTR_VALUE": "FND_RESP|XXA|CUSTOM_ADFIN|STANDARD"
                        },
                        {
                            "ATTR_NAME": "requested_start_date",
                            "ATTR_VALUE": "2019/01/09 15:00:00"
                        },
                        {
                            "ATTR_NAME": "justification",
                            "ATTR_VALUE": "TEST BRLEBRUYN"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }

    }
```

But when I am trying to call the APEX_WEB_SERVICE.make_rest_request process, I am not sure, how can I provide the list of parameters (p_parm_name), as the parameters are of Table type. (The webservice internally calls standard EBS ORacle package UMX_REGISTRATION_PVT.assign_role)

```
   apex_web_service.make_rest_request(
          p_url => 'https://ofd.ntwerpen.be/webservices/rest/XXUA_UMX_PUB/assign_role/',
          p_http_method => 'POST',
          **p_parm_name** => apex_util.string_to_table('requested_for_user_id:wf_role_name:requested_start_date:justification'),              
          p_parm_value => apex_util.string_to_table(l_user_id||':'||l_role_name||':'||l_requested_start_date||':'||l_justification));
```

Can somebody please help me write the correct code to call this procedure.
I beleive, If I am able to give the parameters name correctly in

```
    p_parm_name => apex_util.string_to_table('requested_for_user_id:wf_role_name:requested_start_date:justification')
```

then it will work fine.

Please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned that you are calling the web service using the POST method by providing the JSON as input. You can construct the JSON with values to be passed and pass it to the `P_BODY` parameter of `APEX_WEB_SERVICE.MAKE_REST_REQUEST` procedure.

For constructing JSON, you can use `APEX_JSON` package.

Hope it works..